# How to match a string value with dictionary value stored as list?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comparison

Suppose i have a dictionary

```
A1={'b1':['X','0'],'b2':'Empty',.............,}
```

and then i have a string

```
item=X
```

now i want to match the above string value only with the dict value because other is getting updated dynamically and only string is the way to search.I tried the below code but in vain

```
for key,value in A1.iteritems():
        if value==item:
            print A1.keys()
```

Comment: Read [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume if the value matches then you want the key ?

```
A1 = {'b1': ['X', '0'], 'b2': ['S', 'T'], 'b3': ['X', 'Y']}

item = 'X'

for key, value in A1.iteritems():
    if item in value:
        print key
```

Comment: No!, because it will return true is `X` is sub string of a string value. e.g. `'X' in 'aX'` And it seems op only wants to check in list.

Comment: thanks!! i don't why i was trying to fetch all keys. Dumbass. Thanks a lot mate!!

Comment: @user3787457 your exampled dict and title are not correct.

Comment: but thats what i want.....i have a string which contains the alphabets only and in my dict those alphabets are stored with some other value as a list. So just i want to search that string in dict and get the corresponding key.I guess my mistake is that i asked for matching them which concludes to get some boolean value. Sorry if so.....

Answer (score 1):

For python 3 you can try:
instead of using iteritems() use items()-

```
A1 = {'b1': ['X', '0'], 'b2': ['S', 'T'], 'b3': ['X', 'Y']}

item = 'X'

for key, value in A1.items():
    if item in value:
        print key
```